# Google Sheet - How to FULL OUTER JOIN with one table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I would like to create a tables for my tournament.
I create a table with some players and their leagues.

[image: Players]

I would like to generate matchmaking table, by league, like that

[image: Matchmaking table generated]

I'm to weak with google spreadsheet to do that.
I understood I can't use "JOIN" with "QUERY()" function.
It seems I need to use "ArrayFormula()" and "VLOOKUP()" functions but after hours pasted to try, I failed.

If anyone of you can help me, it will be so great !

Here is a googlesheet with datas : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ThnwVme8f3Ee730w8lTAyEJE9YdxzLEfox8arl5Q4o/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot, I hope my problem is clear :)

Edit : Seems we are limited by number of characters in REPT() function. If there is an other solution than the answer or a "workaround", feel free to share it :)

Comment: @player0 Hello - I shared screenshots with input datas and output desired datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY(SPLIT(IF(
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IF(A3:A="";;A3:A&"♠"&B3:B&"♠"&C3:C)&"♦"); COUNTA(A3:A)); "♦"))<
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(IF(A3:A="";;A3:A&"♠"&B3:B&"♠"&C3:C)&"♦"; COUNTA(A3:A))); "♦")); 
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IF(A3:A="";;A3:A&"♠"&B3:B&"♠"&C3:C)&"♦"); COUNTA(A3:A)); "♦"))&"♠"&
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(IF(A3:A="";;A3:A&"♠"&B3:B&"♠"&C3:C)&"♦"; COUNTA(A3:A))); "♦"));
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(IF(A3:A="";;A3:A&"♠"&B3:B&"♠"&C3:C)&"♦"; COUNTA(A3:A))); "♦"))&"♠"&
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(IF(A3:A="";;A3:A&"♠"&B3:B&"♠"&C3:C)&"♦"); COUNTA(A3:A)); "♦"))); "♠"); 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6
  where Col1 <> Col4 
    and Col3 =  Col6")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello - I've an issue, "REPT" function is limited with 32k characters. With 32 players (real named), formula is broken. Do you have an other solution or a "workaround " ?

Comment: I create a sheet "Case 2 - KO" with more datas to see the issue :)

Comment: Warning : If column A has spaces, formula didn't work well

Answer (score 0):

unlimited:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A3:A)))<=TRANSPOSE(
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A3:A))));;
 FILTER(A3:A&"♦"&B3:B&"♦"&C3:C; A3:A<>"")&"♦"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(A3:A&"♦"&B3:B&"♦"&C3:C; A3:A<>"")))); "♦"); 
 "select Col4,Col5,Col1,Col2,Col6
  where Col2 is not null 
    and Col3 =  Col6
  order by Col4"; 0))
```

[image]